# In SQL Server, what reason is there to use DBCC SHRINKDATABASE with the 'NOTRUNCATE' parameter?

Tags: sql-server

According to Microsoft's documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkdatabase-transact-sql) it says that if you invoke the following command

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(N'MyDb', NOTRUNCATE)
```

that because the NOTRUNCATE parameter is passed that the freed up space will not be returned to the OS and therefore it will appear the database was not shrunk/modified. Moreover, the docs states that the physical file size will not change. So why would you ever do anything but

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(N'MyDb', 20) --20 is the percentage of free space that you want left in the database file after the database has been shrunk
```

or

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(N'MyDb')
```

Isn't the entire point of shrinking the database to free up memory? What am I missing here?

Comment: I believe from reading the link you provided, it's like doing a defrag on your disk drive (yes, I'm old). It moves allocated pages to the front of the file to unallocated space, but keeping the space the same and not shrinking it.

Comment: Though to be clear this will likely  *cause* a great deal of index fragmentation as pages are moved out of key order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started writing a reply, but convinced myself my argument didn’t make sense. I then got another idea, started writing that, and again talked myself out of it. Did it a third time, and once again couldn’t rationalize `NOTRUNCATE`.

The only benefit to not giving up the file space is if you know you’re just going to grab it right back – in which case, why bother with `SHRINKDATABASE`? Stick with rebuilding the indexes to defrag tables without shrinking the database files (which, notoriously, can and will re-fragment the tables) and you’ve got better results than shrinking would produce.

So, nope, I’ve got no idea why you’d ever do this.